# Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain при отправке тестового письма на аккаунт Nodemailer

Tags: node.js

нужна помощь. Использую тестовый аккаунт nodemailer. Пробовал подключать через gmail, настраивал в последнем разрешение стороннего доступа. Результат тот же..Данный пример описывает отправку email на фейковую почту nodemailer, даже он не работает.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
    {
        host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: 'keara.legros71@ethereal.email',
            pass: 'W3Zsu1svH9X9A4EcPC'
        }
    },
    {
        from: 'Mailer Test <keara.legros71@ethereal.email>',
    }
)
const mailer = message => {
    transporter.sendMail(message, (err, info) => {
        if(err) return console.log(err)
        console.log('Email sent: ', info)
    })
}
module.exports = mailer
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mailer = require('./nodemailer')
const app = express()
const PORT = 3001
let user = undefined
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.post('/registration', (req, res) => { 
    if(!req.body.email || !req.body.pass) return res.sendStatus(400)   
    const message = {        
        to: req.body.email,
        subject: 'Congratulations! You are successfully registred on our site',
        text: `Поздравляем, Вы успешно зарегистрировались на нашем сайте!
        
        данные вашей учетной записи:
        login: ${req.body.email}
        password: ${req.body.pass}
        
        Данное письмо не требует ответа.`
    }
    mailer(message) 
    user = req.body 
    res.redirect('/registration') 
    })
app.get('/registration', (req, res) => { 
    if(typeof user !== 'object') return res.sendFile(__dirname + '/registration.html')   
    res.send(`Регистрация прошла успешно! Данные учетной записи отправлены на email: ${user.email}`) 
    user = undefined  
})
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server listening at http://localhost:${PORT}/registration`))
```

саму форму регистрации не привожу, там все банально

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:3001/registration/">
```

и типовая форма с кнопкой..Если кто знает решение данной проблемы..я еще совсем новичок

Comment: в этом коде нет ничего, что могло бы дать ошибку самоподписанного сертификата

Comment: ну так да! у кого -то же этот код работает.. в чем может быть причина у меня?

Comment: причина у тебя может быть в том КОМУ ты отсылаешь сообщение, в ответе mail-сервера адресата. попробуй послать на example@example.com.

Comment: "у кого -то же этот код работает.." - у "всех" этот код работает https://i.stack.imgur.com/v73ZQ.jpg

Comment: @nörbörnën Пробовал example@example.com.. результат тот же.. тот аккаунт с которого уходит это тестовый сгенерированный от https://ethereal.email/ Пробовал example@example.com вбивать вручную в "to", и через инпут... В консоле проверил она точно там..При смене порта выходит уже другая ошибка, но порт тут вроде меня нельзя. ошибка была ECONNRESET.. а так всегда ошибка Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Comment: я еще учусь и нужно протестировать запросы по аутентификации через почту с локального хоста.. С sendgrid были проблемы варификации. Подскажите , как еще можно это сделать..

Answer (score 0):

дело было в антивирусе. отключил на 10 минут экраны аваст и ошибка ушла. при попытке отправить на сервисы mail.ru идет ошибка спам.блокировки самого mail.ru c ссылкой на условное решение